# Strange indentation upon code formatting with MonoDevelop (double indentation)

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

When I use code formatting with MonoDevelop (Shortcut: Ctrl+I), everything gets double-indented:

```
namespace Example
{ 
        public class Test
        {
                public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}: Test", i);
                        }

                    //this would be the desired indentation width!
                        //Not this!
                }
        }
}
```

Checking with the preferences under *Source Code -> Code Formatting -> C# source code* under *Text Style*, **Tab width and Indent width are set to 4**. Nevertheless, I get an indent width of 8 instead of 4, so twice as much indentation.

I'm working on a team-project with Unity3D and using MonoDevelop-Unity version 4.0.1.

Comment: Ran into this using Unity and MonoDevelop on my Mac. Glad this question was asked!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turned out that the solution/project itself had a different code formatting applied and it was overriding my settings from the preferences.

To adjust the **solution/project specific settings**, right click on the `Solution/Project` and choose `Options`. Under `Source Code->Code Formatting->C# source` are the actual tab width and indent width settings for this solution/project that are applied upon code formatting.

Comment: For me it seems that opening Solution Options and toggling a checkbox changed the behavior unexpectedly. I'm guessing a bug in options handling.